# translate the row clicked on listview in popupwindow to the outside activity

Tags: android, android-animation

I would like to translate the row clicked to move to textview on Activity.
I have tried the code below but the view is not translating and moving to the activity screen.

```
public PopupWindow popupWindowDogs() {

   RelativeLayout viewGroup = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout,viewGroup);

    // Creating the PopupWindow
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(getBaseContext());
    popupWindow.setContentView(layout);




     listViewDogs = (ListView)layout.findViewById(R.id.listView10);

    // set our adapter and pass our pop up window contents
    listViewDogs.setAdapter(dogsAdapter(popUpContents));

   listViewDogs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



             c = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            final String playerChanged = c.getText().toString();


            ////////


            final float growTo = 1.1f;

            final long duration = 1000;


            TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(v.getX(), txt.getX(), v.getY(), txt.getY());


            AnimationSet growAndShrink = new AnimationSet(true);
            growAndShrink.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

            growAndShrink.addAnimation(anim);

            growAndShrink.setFillAfter(true);

            view.startAnimation(growAndShrink);


           growAndShrink.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
               @Override
               public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                   popupWindowDogs.dismiss();

                   txt.setText(playerChanged);
               }

               @Override
               public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

               }
           });



        }
    });

    // some other visual settings
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setWidth(250);
    popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // set the list view as pop up window content
    popupWindow.setContentView(listViewDogs);

    return popupWindow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to change the order of `view.startAnimation(growAndShrink);` and `growAndShrink.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() { ... });` First to set everything to the growAndShrink animation and then to start the animation. I think that it could be possible that it doesn't go into the  AnimationListener and never call `txt.setText(playerChanged);` . What do you think?